# Using Firebase to check if a certain product exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm storing some food information inside my database using the Firebase SDK

for IOS with objective c.The information get saved inside my database, but

how can i check if a certain product already exist or not before adding it?

To store the product i'm doing:

```
Firebase *Ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"<my-firebase-db>/list"];

[Ref setValue :@{@"product" : @"randome_product_name"];
```

Please show me how to check if the product exist or not before doing anything so i can learn form it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an IOS dev but this might help - https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#fdatasnapshot_exists